# jquery overlay but in same location as image

Tags: jquery, overlay

I've been trying to recreate the overly functionality that is on http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/products/all-products/

By clicking on the phone it produces a div that displays extra content, I have tried to clone the div and position it but it never seems to work, and messes up the rest of the site.

any insite on how to create this would be great,

Cheers

Comment: The solution is CSS intensive (with some JS thrown in). Without a copy of the code you've got thus far, there's little we can do to assist you. Consider throwing your code up on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i've created a basic version @ http://jsbin.com/eyagin/18  If you hover over the product a you will see that product B and C move to left under product A i'm trying to keep B & C in their current position but allow A to be above B.  I hope that makes sense    Thanks